# Google Data Studio negative lookahead error?

Tags: looker-studio

Why does Google Data Studio have a problem with filtering Pages with this regex?

```
^(?!(\/foopagename\/{0,1})$).*$
```

To clarify, I am trying to create a graph to see how many visitors does a certain page have, so I am filtering out everything else. [Regex101](http://Regex101.com) says it's totally OK.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you create another dimension using "case when" would

```
REGEXP_MATCH(yourDimension, '\/foopagename\/')
```

work?